# pass data in route params to multiple children angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I want to pass data from child A to child B and also child C.
Input field is in child A, I manage to pass the input value from A to B with route params, but don't know how to proceed with the same data further to the last child C.

CHILD A

```
export class CHILDA implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: Router){
  }
  email: any;
  emailPattern = '@'
  ngOnInit():void{}

  navToSecondComp(){
    this.route.navigate(['/childA'], {queryParams:{data:this.email}})
  }
}
```

CHILD A HTML

```
<form id="email-form" #emailForm="ngForm" >
  <div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="email" email name="email" id="email" #emailId="ngModel" type="email" class='form-control' placeholder="INFO@COMPANY.COM" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" (click)="navToCHILDB()"  id="button-submit" >START</button>
```

after clicking START, you're redirected to CHILD B

```
export class CHILDB implements OnInit {
  email: any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) =>{
      console.log(params);
      this.email = params.data
    })
  }
}
```

then I can print the data I got from CHILD A, and then, on button click, I want to be redirected to CHILD C with the same data.
CHILD B html:

```
<div id='welcome' class='text'>Verification email was sent to: <br> {{email}} </div>
<button  type="submit"  id="button-submit">CLOSE THIS WINDOW</button>  <--- this button should go to CHILD C
```

I'm also using routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: CHILDA}, //home page
  {
    path: 'childA',
    component: CHILDB,
    resolve: {
      data: ResolverGuard
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'childC
    component: CHILDC,
    resolve: {
      data: ResolverGuard
    }

}
 ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Do same as you have done in cmpA , so navigate from b to c using navigate () methos

Comment: @GRD but I have to have  constructor(private route: Router){} in child B to navigate to C, but also child B has to have   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }?

Comment: @GRD fixed by adding another property for constructor for child B, thank you!   constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }

Comment: I m looking for work in angular, if you have or any reference then it would be more helpful to me. Thank you. Email I'd is `grdtechlab@gmail.com`